# Do the latest Redhat distros come with SciPy?

Tags: centos, python, redhat-enterprise-linux

I was just curious if any of the latest Redhat/CentOS distros come with SciPy installed. I've heard a rumor that it was included with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed not, but few clicks away.